# Binomial coefficients of $p^a-1$ mod p

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, modules, binomial-coefficients

I need to show that 
$$\binom{p^a-1}{k}\equiv (-1)^k\mod p$$
where $p$ is a prime, $a$ is a positive integer, and $k<p^a-1$.

I think I have done most of the proof, but I'm stuck at the very end.

I have shown that 
$$\frac{(p^a-1)!}{(p^a-1-k)!} \equiv (-1)^kk! \mod p^a$$

so I would be able to get the correct result by dividing through by $k!$ if $\gcd(k!,p^a)=p^b$ for some $b<a$, but it doesn't seem like this is the case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is a method, which is really a special case of [Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem), and is very useful in these cases.

We work with polynomial with coefficients in $F = Z_{p}$, the ring of integers modulo $p$.

You need to know that in $F[x]$ you have $(1 + x)^{p} = 1 + x^{p}$, as
$$
\binom{p}{k} \equiv 0 \pmod{p},
\quad\text{for $0 < k < p$.}
$$

In $F[x]$ we thus have
$$
(1 + x)^{p^{e}} = 1 + x^{p^{e}}
= (1 + x) \sum_{k=0}^{p^{e}-1} (-1)^{k} x^{k},
$$
so that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{p^{e} - 1} \binom{p^{e} - 1}{k} x^{k}
=
(1 + x)^{p^{e} - 1}
=
\sum_{k=0}^{p^{e}-1} (-1)^{k} x^{k}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Look first at the numbers $\binom{p^a}{k}$ with $1 \leq k \leq p^a-1$ :

$$\binom{p^a}{k}=\frac{p^a(p^a-1)\ldots(p^a-k+1)}{k!}$$

Let $v_p(x)$ denote the power of $p$  in the prime factorization of $x$ then using the obvious : $$v_p(x+y)=\min\{v_p(x),v_p(y)\}$$ when $v_p(x) \neq v_p(y)$ we get :

$$v_p(p^a-i)=v_p(i)$$ for every $i$ from $1$ to $k-1$ because $v_p(i)<a$ .

Now put them together so :

$$v_p((p^a-1)\ldots(p^a-k+1))=v_p((k-1)!)$$ and so using it we get :

$$v_p \left( \binom{p^a}{k} \right )=v_p(p^a)-v_p(k)=a-v_p(k) \geq 1$$ because $v_p(k) \leq a-1$ .

This means that : $$p \mid \binom{p^a}{k}$$ for every $1 \leq k \leq p^a-1$ .

Now to get what you want use Pascal's identity :

$$\binom{p^a-1}{k-1}+\binom{p^a-1}{k}=\binom{p^a}{k} \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$$ and so :

$$\binom{p^a-1}{k} \equiv -\binom{p^a-1}{k-1} \pmod{p}$$ for every $1 \leq k \leq p^a-1$ .

Use this congruence repeatedly as follows :

$$\binom{p^a-1}{k} \equiv -\binom{p^a-1}{k-1} \equiv (-1)^2 \cdot \binom{p^a-1}{k-2} \equiv \ldots \equiv (-1)^k \binom{p^a-1}{0} \equiv (-1)^k \pmod{p}$$ as wanted .

Answer (score 0):

Using [Pascal's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule),

For $\displaystyle1\le k< p^a-1,\binom{p^a}k\equiv0\pmod p$

$$\displaystyle\implies\binom{p^a-1}k\equiv-\binom{p^a-1}{k-1}\pmod p\equiv\cdots\equiv(-1)^{k-r}\binom{p^a-1}r$$  for $1\le r\le k$

Now $\displaystyle\binom{p^a-1}1=p^a-1\equiv-1\pmod p$